# Getting error 404 while installing ESLint in Node JS

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I'm trying to install `ESLint` and configuring it for a `NodeJS` project.
When running `npm init @eslint/config` from command line, the following error appears:

```
PS C:\notes-app-backend> npm init @eslint/config
Need to install the following packages:
@eslint/create-config@0.4.6
Ok to proceed? (y) y
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm/enquirer/-/enquirer-2.4.1.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'enquirer@https://repo.huaweicloud.com/repository/npm/enquirer/-/enquirer-2.4.1.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\akhda\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-08-24T06_50_11_679Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enquirer@2.4.1` is currently missing from `repo.huaweicloud.com`.

I guess you are not using `npmjs.com` because it's blocked in your region.

Here are some options:

1. Ask `huaweicloud.com` to re-sync their registry or at least this specific package version (I'm not familiar with the contacting process).
2. Use an alternate registry. Maybe https://npmmirror.com an option?
3. Use npmjs.com from an un-blocked machine, say a remote one. Run the installation once there and copy the project to your local development machine.

If it's not blocked in your region and it was somehow set to `huaweicloud.com` (say by following an online guide whose author is from a "blocked" region), you can just reset `npm` registry to the `npmjs.com` one:

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` this command line is work, thank you for your answer.